# Trying to get max value out of a dictionary in python and getting below error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is my code:
//get_sensor_stats returns a dictionary.

```
static_sensors_stats = get_sensor_stats()
key_max = max(static_sensors_stats.keys(), key=(lambda k: static_sensors_stats[k]))
print('Maximum Value: ',static_sensors_stats[key_max],'Maximum Value Key: ',key_max) 



key_max = max(static_sensors_stats.keys(), key=(lambda k: static_sensors_stats[k]))
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

    During handling of the above exception,
```

Is the keys not a standard function? How to use this right ?

Comment: The name of my dictionary is static_sensors_stats

Comment: `static_sensors_stats` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I am setting static_sensors_stats using return value of a function which returns a dictionary , How can I make static_sensors_stats dictionary ? does dict(static_sensors_stats) do it  ?

Comment: You should provide a small reproducible example. Chances are you will solve the problem yourself while constructing the example.

Comment: static_sensors_stats = get_sensor_stats()===== > This function returns a dictionary
        key_max = max(static_sensors_stats.keys(), key=(lambda k: static_sensors_stats[k]))
        print('Maximum Value: ',static_sensors_stats[key_max],'Maximum Value Key: ',key_max)

Comment: @sudeepmathew: except it clearly does not, the exception tells you it is a list. We can't help you here without more code, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the max value in your static_sensors_stats object (which is a list), you can use `max(static_sensors_stats)`.

If you want get the maximum value of the keys in a dictionary you can use `max(dictionaryname.keys())`.

If you want to get the maximum value of the values in a dictionary you can use `max(dictionaryname.values())`.

In all cases the max() function is operating on a list.

Comment: Does the dictionary get converted to list on setting return value to another variable like in my example  ?

Comment: You state in your question that your `static_sensors_stats` object is a dictionary but your error message is telling you that it is a `list`, which is what Martijn said in his comment. You can test this by using `type(static_sensors_stats)`.